# Android geocode get nearest locations

Tags: android, google-maps, geocoding

I have Geocoder in my application and I want to get location by street name. 
But if try to get location of some, I've get a location of that street in other city.

Is there a way to range found locations by distance from some location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the city into string if you want to find that address which is in your city, simply get the cityname of your location and append that to string but it keep it invisible to the user and if you want to find the address more precisely then you should need more specific input...!!